# Powershell RDP file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to open saved RDP session from my "download" folder.

The following command works. However, I would like it to open *.RDP session files which were saved within 1 minute and delete anything older than 2 minutes.

```
$RDPFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\downloads\Office.rdp"
Invoke-Expression "mstsc.exe /h:850 /w:1000 '$RDPFile'"
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777). Also, show us what you've tried and where, specifically, you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic should be something like this. Please change the placeholders accordingly:

```
$path= "Drive:your\path"
$d = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name LastWriteTime).lastwritetime
if( (((Get-Date)-$d).TotalMinutes) -le 1)
{
Invoke-Expression "mstsc.exe /h:850 /w:1000 '$RDPFile'"
}
else
{
Remove-Item $path\*.rdp -Force
}
```

Note: I have not checked the Invoke part since you have already mentioned its working.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful

Comment: @Maaran: Accepting the answer would be appreciable.